# facing trouble in document conversion pdf to doc,docx and vice versa in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, docx, doc

helo guys !
I am wondering about the solution of .doc/.docx to pdf and vice versa. But the problem i am facing is that files are converted successfully but images do not transferred in new converted file. After searching on google i am here to find the solution.
I actually found the error

```
DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix
```

have a look on my code, thats simple

```
         $domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
        
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
        
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
         
        //Load word file

        $Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(public_path("result.docx")); 

 
        //Save it into PDF
        $PDFWriter = 

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
        $PDFWriter->save(public_path('new-result.pdf')); 
        return 'File has been successfully converted';
```

Basically issue is that when there is image in the result.docx file than errors show up other wise it converted successfully.
I am using phpOffice, DomPdf but could not find an optimize solution.
Any body please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code or more specific details on the issue?

Comment: take a look at this issue it might be related to yours https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/issues/110